# What is the best way to send an image as JSON using the magick R package?

Tags: r

Suppose I read an image into R using `magick::image_read()`.  I would like to send that image to another R session as a JSON payload.  What is the best way to format the JSON payload?  How can I decode the payload in the second R session?  Below is my attempt at formatting the JSON, but I am not sure how to decode the image once it's in that format.

```r
library(magick)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

# read image from the web and make it smaller
img <- 
  image_read('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') %>% 
  image_scale("10") # so the array isn't so large

# extract info from image
img_info <-
  img %>% 
  image_info() %>% 
  as.list()

# extract the bitmap and convert to a string
img_data <- 
  img %>% 
    image_data() %>% 
    as.character()

# what is the best way to take the img_data object into a JSON payload that can be decoded by an external software?  
# does the following work?
# if so, how can i take it and convert it back to the original image?
list('info' = img_info, 'data' = img_data) %>% 
  toJSON(auto_unbox = TRUE) %>% 
  prettify()
#> {
#>     "info": {
#>         "format": "PNG",
#>         "width": 10,
#>         "height": 3,
#>         "colorspace": "sRGB",
#>         "matte": true,
#>         "filesize": 0,
#>         "density": "72x72"
#>     },
#>     "data": [
#>         "42",
#>         "85",
#>         "f4",
#>         "66",
#>         "42",
#>         "85",
#>         "f4",
#>         "52",
#>         "60",
#>         "79",
#>         "d1",
#>         "07",
#>         "ea",
#>         "43",
#>         "35",
#>         "23",
#>         "fb",
#>         "bc",
#>         "05",
#>         "09",
#>         "fb",
#>         "bc",
#>         "05",
#>         "1b",
#>         "42",
#>         "85",
#>         "f4",
#>         "14",
#>         "3d",
#>         "91",
#>         "bc",
#>         "27",
#>         "4a",
#>         "9c",
#>         "4f",
#>         "47",
#>         "ea",
#>         "43",
#>         "35",
#>         "19",
#>         "42",
#>         "85",
#>         "f4",
#>         "6f",
#>         "42",
#>         "85",
#>         "f4",
#>         "51",
#>         "90",
#>         "66",
#>         "9b",
#>         "a8",
#>         "ea",
#>         "43",
#>         "35",
#>         "5e",
#>         "f5",
#>         "95",
#>         "14",
#>         "95",
#>         "fb",
#>         "bc",
#>         "05",
#>         "74",
#>         "44",
#>         "86",
#>         "f1",
#>         "70",
#>         "40",
#>         "89",
#>         "e1",
#>         "80",
#>         "a4",
#>         "69",
#>         "40",
#>         "b6",
#>         "ea",
#>         "43",
#>         "35",
#>         "6c",
#>         "42",
#>         "85",
#>         "f4",
#>         "12",
#>         "42",
#>         "85",
#>         "f4",
#>         "38",
#>         "c2",
#>         "53",
#>         "62",
#>         "06",
#>         "ea",
#>         "43",
#>         "35",
#>         "36",
#>         "fa",
#>         "b7",
#>         "07",
#>         "11",
#>         "fb",
#>         "bc",
#>         "05",
#>         "2b",
#>         "42",
#>         "85",
#>         "f4",
#>         "5a",
#>         "41",
#>         "86",
#>         "ef",
#>         "6f",
#>         "8d",
#>         "76",
#>         "44",
#>         "1e",
#>         "ea",
#>         "43",
#>         "35",
#>         "2c"
#>     ]
#> }
#>
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Asking for the "best way" is very subjective. What exactly are the requirements? Is it just that you need to be able to serialize the object? It would probably be more efficient (smaller) to encode the bytes with base64 encoding. Or are you just trying to decode the format that you've built?

Comment: @MrFlick my main goal is to be able to convert it back to the original image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary data in JSON is usually encoded as Base64, with `jsonlite::serializeJSON()` / `jsonlite::unserializeJSON()` we can just pass an object (which can be a list; though not a `magick` object itself as it's an `externalptr`) :

```r
library(magick)
#> Linking to ImageMagick 6.9.12.98
#> Enabled features: cairo, freetype, fftw, ghostscript, heic, lcms, pango, raw, rsvg, webp
#> Disabled features: fontconfig, x11
library(jsonlite)
library(magrittr)

img <- 
  image_read('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') %>% 
  image_scale("10")


json_str <- 
  list(
    info = image_info(img) %>% as.list(), 
    data = image_data(img)
  ) %>% 
  serializeJSON() 

prettify(json_str)
#> {
#>     "type": "list",
#>     "attributes": {
#>         "names": {
#>             "type": "character",
#>             "attributes": {
#> 
#>             },
#>             "value": [
#>                 "info",
#>                 "data"
#>             ]
#>         }
#>     },
#>     "value": [
#>         {
#>             "type": "list",
#>             "attributes": {
#>                 "names": {
#>                     "type": "character",
#>                     "attributes": {
#> 
#>                     },
#>                     "value": [
#>                         "format",
#>                         "width",
#>                         "height",
#>                         "colorspace",
#>                         "matte",
#>                         "filesize",
#>                         "density"
#>                     ]
#>                 }
#>             },
#>             "value": [
#>                 {
#>                     "type": "character",
#>                     "attributes": {
#> 
#>                     },
#>                     "value": [
#>                         "PNG"
#>                     ]
#>                 },
#>                 {
#>                     "type": "integer",
#>                     "attributes": {
#> 
#>                     },
#>                     "value": [
#>                         10
#>                     ]
#>                 },
#>                 {
#>                     "type": "integer",
#>                     "attributes": {
#> 
#>                     },
#>                     "value": [
#>                         3
#>                     ]
#>                 },
#>                 {
#>                     "type": "character",
#>                     "attributes": {
#> 
#>                     },
#>                     "value": [
#>                         "sRGB"
#>                     ]
#>                 },
#>                 {
#>                     "type": "logical",
#>                     "attributes": {
#> 
#>                     },
#>                     "value": [
#>                         true
#>                     ]
#>                 },
#>                 {
#>                     "type": "integer",
#>                     "attributes": {
#> 
#>                     },
#>                     "value": [
#>                         0
#>                     ]
#>                 },
#>                 {
#>                     "type": "character",
#>                     "attributes": {
#> 
#>                     },
#>                     "value": [
#>                         "72x72"
#>                     ]
#>                 }
#>             ]
#>         },
#>         {
#>             "type": "raw",
#>             "attributes": {
#>                 "class": {
#>                     "type": "character",
#>                     "attributes": {
#> 
#>                     },
#>                     "value": [
#>                         "bitmap",
#>                         "rgba"
#>                     ]
#>                 },
#>                 "dim": {
#>                     "type": "integer",
#>                     "attributes": {
#> 
#>                     },
#>                     "value": [
#>                         4,
#>                         10,
#>                         3
#>                     ]
#>                 }
#>             },
#>             "value": "QoX0ZkKF9FJgedEH6kM1I/u8BQn7vAUbQoX0FD2RvCdKnE9H6kM1GUKF9G9ChfRRkGabqOpD\nNV71lRSV+7wFdESG8XBAieGApGlAtupDNWxChfQSQoX0OMJTYgbqQzU2+rcHEfu8BStChfRa\nQYbvb412RB7qQzUs"
#>         }
#>     ]
#> }
#>
```

Read image from serialized JSON:

```r
img2 <- unserializeJSON(json_str)$data %>% image_read()
identical(
  image_data(img), 
  image_data(img2)
)
#> [1] TRUE
```

If you need more control, you can combine `serialize()`/`unserialize()` from `base` with `base64_enc()`/`base64_dec()` from `jsonlite`:

```r
img_info <-
  img %>% 
  image_info() %>% 
  as.list()

# toJSON uses base64_enc() here 
img_json <- 
  list('info' = img_info, 
       'data' = image_data(img) %>% serialize(connection = NULL)) %>% 
  toJSON(auto_unbox = TRUE)
prettify(img_json)
#> {
#>     "info": {
#>         "format": "PNG",
#>         "width": 10,
#>         "height": 3,
#>         "colorspace": "sRGB",
#>         "matte": true,
#>         "filesize": 0,
#>         "density": "72x72"
#>     },
#>     "data": "WAoAAAADAAQDAgADBQAAAAAFVVRGLTgAAAMYAAAAeEKF9GZChfRSYHnRB+pDNSP7vAUJ+7wF\nG0KF9BQ9kbwnSpxPR+pDNRlChfRvQoX0UZBmm6jqQzVe9ZUUlfu8BXREhvFwQInhgKRpQLbq\nQzVsQoX0EkKF9DjCU2IG6kM1Nvq3BxH7vAUrQoX0WkGG72+NdkQe6kM1LAAABAIAAAABAAQA\nCQAAAAVjbGFzcwAAABAAAAACAAQACQAAAAZiaXRtYXAABAAJAAAABHJnYmEAAAQCAAAAAQAE\nAAkAAAADZGltAAAADQAAAAMAAAAEAAAACgAAAAMAAAD+"
#> }
#> 

# we need to direct bes64-encoded object through base64_dec() ourselves
img2 <- 
  fromJSON(img_json)$data %>% 
  base64_dec() %>%  
  unserialize() %>% 
  image_read()

identical(
  image_data(img),
  image_data(img2)
)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using `{imager}` package:

```r
img <- imager::load.image("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png") |>
  imager::resize(-10, -10)

img
#> Image. Width: 27 pix Height: 9 pix Depth: 1 Colour channels: 4

j <- list("im_width" = dim(img)[1], "im_height" = dim(img)[2],
          "im_depth" = dim(img)[3], "im_channels" = dim(img)[4],
          "r" = img[,,1], "g" = img[,,2], "b" = img[,,3]) |>
  jsonlite::toJSON(auto_unbox = TRUE) |>
  jsonlite::prettify()

un <- jsonlite::fromJSON(j)

qw <- array(c(un$r, un$g, un$b), 
            c(un$im_width,un$im_height,un$im_depth, un$im_channels))

newimg <- imager::as.cimg(qw)

newimg
#> Image. Width: 27 pix Height: 9 pix Depth: 1 Colour channels: 4

plot(newimg)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>