# Turn `magick` object into raw vector

Tags: r, raw, magick

I need the mime type and raw vector of an image to upload it to an API that I'm working with. I would like to do this with the `magick` package, but can't figure out how to get a proper raw vector out of a magick object. This is how I read in the image and get it's mime type:

```r
library(magick)
example_image <- "https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5yfi.jpg?s=256&g=1"
img <- image_read(example_image)
image_mimetype <- paste0("image/", tolower(image_info(img)$format))
image_mimetype
#> [1] "image/jpeg"
```

My current workaround (that works) is to save the `magick` object to disk and read in the file as raw again:

```
tmp <- tempfile()
image_write(img, tmp)
img_raw <- readBin(tmp, "raw", file.info(tmp)$size)
head(img_raw)
#> [1] ff d8 ff e0 00 10
object.size(img_raw)
#> 24272 bytes
```

I looked through the magick github repo for mentions of raw and found that you can get a raw array like so:

```
img_raw <- img[[1]]
img_raw
#> 3 channel 256x256 bitmap array: 'bitmap' raw [1:3, 1:256, 1:256] 54 55 4d 4b ...
```

It's possible to turn this into a vector:

```
img_raw <- as.raw(img[[1]])
head(img_raw)
#> [1] 54 55 4d 4b 4c 44
object.size(img_raw)
#> 196656 bytes
```

But the vector is about 8 times as big and the API does not accept it as valid jpeg.

<sup>Created on 2024-01-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Presumably the representation that magick keeps in memory is not compressed; otherwise the operations it performs on images would have to be lossy and inefficient, with decompression, process, and compression stages. Why not simply read the data with `readBin` instead of loading it with magick and saving it again? There are a finite set [image mimetypes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image) which you could either get from magick or just assign based on file extension?

Comment: What's the API and what are you using for making API requests? For `httr2` multipart requests, file content is added through `curl::from_file()`; for `httr` there's `upload_file()`.  You could also serialize image data and include it in JSON payload as bse64 string ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/77751907/646761 ), though it's rather likely that it's unexpected input for the remote service.

Comment: The API is the AT Protocol (Bluesky). `readBin` is essentially what I'm doing, but it can't handle remote files and since I'm using magick anyway to get the mimetype and other information, I would like to go through that package. The note about `httr2`, which I'm indeed using is very interesting!

Comment: As it seems to be just a file upload, `httr2::req_body_file()` should be able to guess MIME type from file extension and could replace your `req_headers()` and `req_raw()`, though it works only with local file paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `image_write` silently returns the infomation you need, so you don't need to explicitly write it to a file (use `path=NULL`), so you can replace

```
tmp <- tempfile()
image_write(img, tmp)
img_raw <- readBin(tmp, "raw", file.info(tmp)$size)
```

by

```
img_raw <- image_write(img, NULL)
```

to avoid writing to file and produce the same output.

I'm not sure this behaviour is clear from the documentation, but you can see what's going on from the source code of `image_write()`.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! I mentioned your answer in the package source: https://github.com/JBGruber/atrrr/commit/1f55c8dee6ded1ef942cff5b2e950cf9cedb5b99